# Какая есть библиотека на Python для системы Linux, чтобы копировать текст в буфер обмена

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Мне необходимо копировать текст из переменной в буфер обмена на Linux. Есть ли такая библиотека? Надо наподобие библиотеки для Windows - pyperclip

Пример кода для винды:

```
import pyperclip
my_text = 'text for copy'
pyperclip.copy(my_text)
```

Comment: `pyperclip` - кроссплатформенный модуль, который работает на Windows / UNIX(Linux) / MacOS ...

Comment: Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.
Вот что выдается при использовании pyperclip

Comment: [On Linux, this module makes use of the xclip or xsel commands, which should come with the os. Otherwise run `sudo apt-get install xclip`](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/)

Comment: При попытки скачать эти пакета, как сказано в документации выдаются ошибкии (https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#not-implemented-error) 

pip3 install gtk - ERROR: No matching distribution found for gtk
pip3 install PyQt4 - ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyQt4
sudo apt-get install xsel  - Неудовлетворённые зависимости
sudo apt-get install xclip - Неудовлетворённые зависимости

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` - обновите список пакетов

Comment: Все я понял, проблема была в уже установленных пакета и они конфликтовали. Все исправил и уже работает все

Answer (score 1):

**pyperclip** - кроссплатформенный модуль, который работает на Windows / UNIX(Linux) / MacOS

**Для работы на Linux нужно установить данные пакеты:**

- sudo apt-get install xsel
- sudo apt-get install xclip

*Если возникнет проблема ("Неудовлетворённые зависимости ") при установки данных пакетов, то использовать следующую программу - **sudo apt --fix-broken install***

Если не получится, попробуйте установить следующие библиотеки:

- pip install gtk
- pip install PyQt4